Update HTML based on timestamps in Templates
I'm new to Vue and have a small problem.
I have a small Chat and every Message has its timestamp to display the current time-difference. Every chat has like 150 Messages.
Task:
My task now would be to update the time-text of every single message every 60 seconds, so the information is more accurate. Instead of "4 minutes ago" there should be "5 minutes ago" displayed after 60 seconds.
Problem:
I don't know how to setup this part. How can I accomplish this target without setting an interval on each message. I would like to have one single interval. But I don't know how to tell the Template to fetch this single information again.
Messages:
{
   "id": 1,
   "time": 1717493931716,
   "message": "Hello Sir!"
}

In my Message-Template I call a pinia-store function to resolve the time-text:
   <script lang="ts" setup>
      ...
      import { useChatStore } from '@/stores/modules/chat';
      const chatStore = useChatStore();
      const currentTimeText = ref(chatStore.getFormattedTime(props.message.timeFormatted));

   </script>
   <template>
       <span class="text-xs ms-1 text-secondary">{{ currentTimeText }}</span>
   </template>


The function in the store is:
    getFormattedTime(dateString: string): string {
      const date = new Date(dateString);
      const now  = new Date();
      const diff = Math.abs(now - date) / 1000; // Differenz in Sekunden
      
      if (diff < 60) {
        return this.localizedString("timeFormat.now");
      } else if (diff < 120) {
        return this.localizedString("timeFormat.1MinuteAgo");
      } else if (diff < 300) {
        return this.localizedString("timeFormat.5MinutesAgo");
      } else if (diff < 1800) {
        
        const minutes = Math.floor(diff / 60);
        return this.localizedString("timeFormat.XMinutesAgo", [minutes]);
      } else if (this.time_isSameDay(now, date)) {
        return this.localizedString("timeFormat.today") + ", " + this.time_formatTime(date);
      } else if (this.time_isYesterday(now, date)) {
        return this.localizedString("timeFormat.yesterday") + ", " + this.time_formatTime(date);
      } else if (this.time_isSameYear(now, date)) {
        return this.time_formatDate(date) + ", " + this.time_formatTime(date);
      } else {
        return this.time_formatDateLong(date) + ", " + this.time_formatTime(date);
      }
    },


Honestly, I would go with Websockets for the realtime part and a date formatter with datefns to not worry too much about the manual part. They have some good formatting in that exact same format.

@kissu I had the idea to setup intervals only for "new" messages, so if the else part is comming, no update is required because it's the default time display. And there should be not many messages until the else part is comming.

"else part" as in? Doesn't break anything I said above.

There should be helper function that uses Vue reactivity for updates. It can return a ref with updated value, or return string value but trigger an interval update when it's used in reactive context, similarly to how t() reacts to locale change in Vue I18n.
const count = ref(0);
const interval = setInterval(() => count.value++, 60000);
onScopeDispose(() => { clearInterval(interval) }); // Clean up

function getReactiveTimeRef(value) {
  return computed(() => {
    count.value; // Recompute every minute
    return getFormattedTime(toValue(value)); 
  });
}

function getReactiveTimeString(value) {
  count.value;
  return getFormattedTime(value);
}

Due to how the helpers work, they allow the following uses:

const formattedTimeRef = getReactiveTimeRef(() => time)

const formattedTimeRef = getReactiveTimeRef(timeRef)

const formattedTimeRef = computed(() => getReactiveTimeString(time))

{{ getReactiveTimeString(timestamp) }}


The helpers and count can be defined in component scope, but doing this in global scope like Pinia store or Vue plugin will synchronize string updates for better UX and performance.
